# Expectations of random variables. Can someone help me make sure I'm setting up the equation right?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

the question asks, The first quartile of the distribution X is defined as the value $q_1$
Such that

P(X ⩽ $q_1$) = 0.25

If X ~ f(x) = 4x^3 **1**(0 < x < 1) what is q$_1$?

I feel like I should set it up like this:

$$\int_0^ \frac14 4x^3 \,dx= \frac14$$

thanks for the help :)

Comment: $\int_0^{q_1} 4x^3 \,dx= \frac14$. Now integrate left side which gives you $(q_1)^4 = \frac14$

Comment: wait, I think I made a typo, the integral should be from 0 to 1 not 1/4 do I still calculate it the same?